# MySQL: combining queries for speed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, lamp

MySQL database with more than 10 million rows. I am currently displaying the first ten results **and then** counting the total number of matches. The contents of the first ten results are echoed in PHP. **Then** the total number of hits is displayed.

First statement (fast):

```
SELECT * FROM `bigTable` WHERE `name` LIKE '%steve%' LIMIT 10
```

Second statement (slow):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `bigTable` WHERE `name` LIKE '%steve%'
```

I want to combine these queries to increase speed. I want to preserve the functionality where users see the first ten results, while they are waiting for the system to find the total count. Is this possible?

Comment: use a separate query run by ajax to display the count data please

Answer (score 2):

Your second query requires inspecting the name column for every row. If you need that number with that condition it will always be slow.

You might consider keeping a separate table with **word-occurs in row(id)**, (keep it updated with all inserts/updates/deletes, can be maintained with a trigger). Your search will always be a join to this table with word='name' (to be indexed on this column: word).

You can also use FULLTEXT indexing as suggested by others; if available to you.

Comment: (That's what a `FULLTEXT` index automates.)

Comment: I didn't know MySql had FULLTEXT indexing; thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a "word", then use a `FULLTEXT` index and `MATCH(name) AGAINST("+steve")` -- both queries will by *much* faster.

If, on the other hand, you must search for middles of words (etc), then doing it with `LIKE` and a leading wild card is as fast as it gets.  But, the `COUNT` will always have to scan the entire table, and the `SELECT *` will scan until the end of the table, too, *unless* it finds 10 before that.

Depending on what version you are using, you may be able to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS`, but it won't be much faster.